# Woocommerce change variation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I need some help with woocommerce. I have some subscription products in my shop. Before the customer buy the product he has to select the product variation (example the taste). After he bought the product he can see it in his account area. The problem is that I want to give the customer the option to change the variation after buying it directly from his account area. My plan is that the function should loop over the variation who are available for the product and write it in a dropdown list. Finaly the customer can select the variation in the dropdown and press a safe button. No the variation should change in the database in woocommerce. I searched a lot but there is no function for this. I hope you have a Idea how I can deal with this.

I'm using the Subscriptio plugin.

Thanks a lot for your help!